# What's the best way to deploy changes to several databases on multiple Postgresql Databases servers

Tags: postgresql, deployment, ansible

I was wondering if there is a better way to deploy changes to several Postgres databases on multiple servers. I have been using Ansible for this task, I have a playbook that basically copies the changes to the server, applies them to the databases, and collect the logs using `psql`:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f my_changes.sql  > log.out 2> log.err
```

But I have some problems with this approach with the `INDEX` creations. Sometimes it takes several minutes or hours to create the index and I need to use background jobs with ansible using [async & poll](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) to allow Ansible run long tasks wihtout close the ssh connection. Also, I think I am using Ansible wrong since it is a configuration tool and this kind of task always reflect a change on the server...

Hoping you guys can tell me better approaches, tools( I heard that [pgbarman](https://pgbarman.org/) can also deploy changes) or improvements on my current solution

Answer (score 0):

I did a search for

[apply schema changes to multiple PostgreSQL databases](https://www.google.com/search?q=apply+schema+changes+to+multiple+PostgreSQL+databases&rlz=1C1GCEB_en&biw=1920&bih=1038&sxsrf=AOaemvLAlEXFxBLMsEkrWmjjAz-D0X9Ruw%3A1635776835132&ei=Q_l_YbOuB8T2kwWE26eYAQ&oq=apply+schema+changes+to+multiple+PostgreSQL+databases&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgjELACECdKBAhBGABQ_FBY-1NgjlhoAXACeACAAb4BiAHSApIBAzIuMZgBAKABAcgBCcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjz28HJr_fzAhVE-6QKHYTtCRM4ChDh1QMIDg&uact=5)

...and in the results I found this little gem:

- [DbSchema](https://dbschema.com/)

A possible candidate for your situation.

> **Disclaimer**
> I in no way endorse the product, nor am I in any way related to the software vendor